# Combine sequences with similar headers in fasta file

Tags: python

I have a fasta file which contains sequence like the following:

```
>1 | A
actgcttctttcaa
>1 | B
cccaatggtac
>1 | C
ttccggaaa
>2 | A
actgcggcaa
>2 | B
cccaatac
>2 | C
tacatta
........
>1000 | A
actgactg
>1000 | B
aaccggttaacc
>1000 | C
ttcgttcg
```

I wish to combine the sequences whose header with the same numbers, like this

```
>1
actgcttctttcaacccaatggtacttccggaaa
>2
cccaataccccaatactacatta
............
>1000
actgactgaaccggttaaccttcgttcg
```

Now I have no idea how to do this? Is there anyone who could help with this?

Comment: Try converting FASTA to TSV. Use Pandas to manipulate your data and convert the TSV back into FASTA. There are tools for the interformat conversion online. I checked.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think it could be the correct way.

Comment: Also see https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/2651

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3:

```
from collections import defaultdict

with open(input_file_name) as f:
    d = defaultdict(list)
    lines = [l.strip() for l in f.readlines()]
    lines = [l for l in lines if l]
    if len(lines) % 2:
        print("WARNING: Odd number of lines")

    for line1, line2 in zip(lines[::2], lines[1::2]):
        n, *_ = line1[1:].split('|')
        d[int(n)].append(line2.strip())

    lines = ['>{:d}\n{:s}\n'.format(k, ''.join(v)) for k, v in d.items()]

with open(output_file_name, 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(lines)
```

The above code *assumes* that for a given number ID (e.g., 1, 2, 3, ...), sub-strings (or whatever they are called) come in alphabetic order (A, B, C). What I want to say is that this will not work *if*, for example,

```
>1 | B
cccaatggtac
>1 | C
ttccggaaa
>1 | A
actgcttctttcaa
```

and you expect to still get `actgcttctttcaacccaatggtacttccggaaa`.